# Is there a way to htaccess password protect www.somedomain/?data&some-url?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, security

I want to secure www.somedomain/?data&some-url with htaccess and let the www.somedomain to work fine but when accessing that URL directly or from a link, the htaccess protects it.

Is it possible?

---

fine..

lets make this "easier"

my htaccess file is this but it wont work

```
<files ?some&data>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /dir/passwd
require valid-user
</files>
```

Comment: Do you have control over some-url? If so, this is possible, otherwise no. In the first case, you could generate a hashed secret that is part of the `some-url` link, and the site is only shown if the secret is found to be valid. This technique usually incorporates the time too, so the link will only work for a couple of minutes before becoming invalid. (As it is, it is worth adding more detail into your question - what are you trying to do? Please add that response into your question, thanks).

Comment: I dont understand that "do you have control over some-url". 

I am trying to secure CMSimple login page that url is /?page&login if that help anything

Comment: I am asking if you have administrative control over the some-url website. Are you able to add a security mechanism to that site?

Comment: yes, I can modify my own coding and files on my webserver

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a workaround: you can use .htaccess to redirect that specific path (/?data&some-url) to an .htaccess protected dummy folder .e.g /myproctedtforlder/. 
Prix had a point by mentioning the QUERY_STRING condition. I modified my answer with full details. The first thing to do is rename index.php to whatever name you want, in this case I used index2.php.

So your main page's .htaccess would contain these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} data&some-url
RewriteRule ^$ /myprotectedfolder/ [QSA,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|jfif|bmp|css|js|txt|xml)$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^$ index2.php [QSA,L] 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index2.php [QSA,L]
```

and then your protected folder (/myprotectedfolder/) .htaccess would look like:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home/username/myprotectedfolder/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

I am not giving further details about the .htpassword, you can find many examples like in here: http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess.
In the 'answer' easy details you provided below, you should be careful that in  tag you should provide file names format (e.g index.(php|html)) not the query string. In your case you are providing query string. So that's not working to start with. Could you please remove that 'answer' and put it as a comment?

Comment: Except you cannot catch query string on the `RewriteRule` you need a condition with `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: True. My aim was to give a general workaround about how to solve the problem. Details are to taken care of.

Comment: That is by far a too big detail to be left out in this case.

Comment: that is not rewriting to specified folder with ?data&some-url

Comment: I edited the answer based on Prix's comment with query_string.

Answer (score 1):

Hi theres well written article about this

[1](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/): [heres the Link of that article](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/)

I could write some of that text here and mention source but that some text may couldnt be helpful for all

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can show auth dialogue for a particular query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## force BASIC auth for a specific query parameter
#set PSSWD_NEEDED var to 1 if query string is matched
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)data&some-url(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?/?$ index.php/%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

# set PSSWD_NEEDED var to 1 if URI is /index.php/...
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/index\.php/data&some-url" PSSWD_NEEDED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /dir/passwd
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=PSSWD_NEEDED
Satisfy any
```